# How to run a short program repeatedly and then time it in command line

Tags: bash, time, terminal, fish

I have an executable as `a.out`. When I do `time ./a.out`, it gives me run time like 0.0083s. I suspect that the number is not very accurate when the program finishes too soon so I would like to run this executable 100 times and take the average.

How can I achieve this in a terminal (bash, os X)?